# Finding a list of possible ServerSockets

Tags: java, client-server, serversocket

I want to program a game that involves a client-server option for a network.

For this, I need to be able to get a list of all people that are hosting a server on their computer but the Socket class requires a name of the computer. Is it possible to get this list and if so, then how?

Thanks you very much

Comment: you can use UDP and multicast/broadcast to find the computers in the network that will reply to the call

Comment: jini-- now apache river was built to resolve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [`MulticastSocket`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/MulticastSocket.html) on the client to listen for broadcast UDP packets from the server. See [Broadcasting to Multiple Recipients](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/broadcasting.html) and have your server send one out every few seconds.

Comment: what if there were multiple servers on the local network that the user wants to connect to. I want to get a list of all servers on the network.